# Maven JSP Pre-compile

Tags: maven

I am using Maven to rebuild a Java web-app using JSP Pre-compile.
Looking for any advice since getting the following runtime error in tomcat stdout log:

```
INFO   | jvm 1  | 2017/08/08 10:47:30 | Aug 08, 2017 10:47:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO   | jvm 1  | 2017/08/08 10:47:30 | SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet ldi-adapter
INFO   | jvm 1  | 2017/08/08 10:47:30 | java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1  | 2017/08/08 10:47:30 |     at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldResourcePath(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
INFO   | jvm 1  | 2017/08/08 10:47:30 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:433)
```

Here is POM file snip:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
   <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0</version>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>compile-jsp</id>
           <goals>
               <goal>jspc</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Command line:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=H:\Workspace35BLDIToLearnBridge\lditolearnbridge_v2\BBLearnLDIAdapter -Dmaven.home=C:\Users\rseletsk\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-1\172.3968.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\rseletsk\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-1\172.3968.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf -javaagent:C:\Users\rseletsk\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-1\172.3968.16\lib\idea_rt.jar=51404:C:\Users\rseletsk\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-1\172.3968.16\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\rseletsk\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-1\172.3968.16\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.2.3 package

```
Tomcat embedded dependencies:

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
<version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
<version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What's your command line call? and do you have tomcat as a dependency? If so, what's the snippet?

Comment: Thank you Nic - just edited post.